# Convert class component to a function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, class, redux

I've created a web application project with React Redux and TypeScript. (In VS 2019).

A template project was created for me with few class components (Counter, WeatherForecast ....).
Now, I'm trying to convert the class component - Counter - to a Function component.
Currently without a successes.
I Need Help for it.

The class component is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
import * as CounterStore from '../store/Counter';

type CounterProps =
    CounterStore.CounterState &
    typeof CounterStore.actionCreators &
    RouteComponentProps<{}>;

class Counter extends React.PureComponent<CounterProps> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Counter</h1>

                <p>This is a simple example of a React component.</p>

                <p aria-live="polite">Current count: <strong>{this.props.count}</strong></p>

                <button type="button"
                    className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                    onClick={() => { this.props.increment(); }}>
                    Increment
                </button>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
};

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.counter,
    CounterStore.actionCreators
)(Counter);
```

Comment: Can you please share the function component part where you got stuck? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response. I understood how it should be done:

```
type CounterComponentProps =
     CounterStore.CounterState &
     typeof CounterStore.actionCreators &
     RouteComponentProps<{}>;

const Counter = (props: CounterComponentProps) => {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>

          <h1>Counter</h1>

          <p>This is a simple example of a React component.</p>

          <p aria-live="polite">Current count: <strong>{props.count}</strong></p>

          <button type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                onClick={() => { props.increment(); }}>
                Increment
          </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );

};

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.counter,
    CounterStore.actionCreators)(Counter as any)
```